# App Icon not showing up, although I have added in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I have added the icon as shown in the pic below but I am still not seeing the icon in my device or simulator.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do a clean install (i.e. remove the app from the simulator)? And you should check that the images are "compiled" with your target (see "Target Membership" section in the file inspector of the image)

Answer (score 34):

This might be an XCode 5 bug that the added icons are not actually included in the app bundle, but you can work around it by going to Build Phases, expand Copy Bundle Resources, then press the "+" sign in the bottom to manually add the icon files to this category.

In addition iOS 5/6 seems to have a bug that the screen doesn't update the app icon even if the icon files are included in the bundle. To work around it (as suggested by josema.vitaminew at [App Icon not changing when app version is updated in iOS 5 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787178/app-icon-not-changing-when-app-version-is-updated-in-ios-5-simulator)) you can drag the app icon into a folder, then iOS will update the appearance of it.

Comment: I hit this same issue because I had an icons folder that I added to the project, without clicking the target membership box.  You can open your target settings and highlight each image in your sidebar while holding command, then click the target membership in the File Inspector in the right sidebar.  This has the same effect as adding them to the build phase.  Apple should have insured that any image that was set in App Icons be added to the target, so this is definitely their fault.

Comment: These kind of things always amaze me... how can Apple have such errors in one of the most important software they have???

Comment: Re-Adding the files to the project did the trick. "Click on the icon and/or splash folder inside XCode and choose "Add files to (project)..." and choose the required ones and that works. At least on XCode 5.

Answer (score 25):

If using the Asset Catalog, it might be worth also checking whether `Images.xcassets` holds all your targets as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: In my case i can't select my target. I must add `Copy Bundle Resources` in my target `Build Phase` in Xcode simply click `+`

Comment: This was my problem, too. Xcode 9/iOS 11. Not sure why my target was unselected. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on adp's answer, if anyone has switched to asset catalogs but they stopped working, and still can't find a solution for Asset Catalog, Images.xcassets, AppIcon or LaunchImage not working, here is a reproduction of the same problem I encountered, and the solution:

I had upgraded to Xcode 6 and opened a project created by an earlier version (4 or 5, not sure) and no matter what I did, AppIcons and LaunchImages absolutely would show up when I ran the app in either iOS Simulator or the device.

- I tried Xcode->Product->Clean, Xcode->Window->Organizer->Projects->Derived Data->Delete..., relaunching Xcode and the iOS Simulator, then rebuilding and relaunching the app (failed).
- I tried "Reset Contents and Settings..." in iOS Simulator and even deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData//Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos and relaunching the app (failed).
- I tried archiving the project, hoping that it was just an issue with the iOS Simulator, but the icon in the Organizer-Archives window was still shown as the default white square with lines, confirming that the icon would also not show on a device (a helpful trick to have when no device is handy).  (failed).
- I tried choosing "Don't use asset catalogs" in Target Settings and creating a new AppIcon-2 and LaunchImage-2 (failed).  ***-this is what cost me at least 2 more hours, because this should have worked and the fact that it didn't revealed the bug in Xcode but I just couldn't see it-***
- I tried creating a new project from the single view template and compared all of the Info.plist settings (failed).
- I tried comparing the new project's Contents.json with mine in Images.xcassets (failed).
- I tried dragging the images from the left sidebar Navigator into the AppIcon image wells, hoping that they were just not being copied in a build phase for some reason (failed).
- **Finally in exasperation at the thought of having to create a new project just to fix the icons, I tried deleting Images.xcassets in the left sidebar Navigator and choosing "Move to Trash", then quitting Xcode and relaunching in case it cached anything.  Then when I went to click the App Icons Source popup menu, it only showed "Don't use asset catalogs".  I had to select it in order to bring back the "Use Asset Catalog" button.  Then I was able to create new AppIcons and LaunchImages, drag images to the wells, build and launch the app in iOS Simulator and finally see icons appear properly.**

So the problem appears to be with how Xcode stores Images.xcassets inside the project, and not with target membership, derived data, **or anything in Images.xcassets itself**.  You must remove your assets file and create a fresh one, then drag images to wells by hand again.

It took me 3 hours of research to solve something that should have "just worked" and the entire process of having to manually create individually sized art assets has been so tedious over the years that it has personally cost me countless hours of busywork.

Hopefully this bug workaround helps someone avoid the frustration I went through.  I can't help with the friction of manually sizing art assets, but I highly recommend the [Icon Slayer](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/) website to automate that (of which I have no affiliation).

Comment: I spent two days trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: That's what worked in my case. Creating a new image asset from scratch didn't work.

Comment: Vectorize everything.

Comment: Thanks!, this worked for me... it's because once Jobs' dead, it seems Apple hired people that doesn't care about the company or are plain dumbs. Add all wasted hours of us developers trying to figure this out!... stupid!.

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered the same problem when the project is switching from xcode5 to xcode6 . The solution is just click on the icon in the image asset,open the right panel , just tick the iOS version option in the panel,add the icons that are blank  run it again ... It worked for me[image]

Answer (score 3):

I want to add my solution, where the problem is only isolated to the iPad, my app icon will not show only for iPads.  After trying all the solution above, and I looked in the info.plist and found this flag that was not there before the problem with iPads.  A new key/value has been added called "CFBundleIcons~ipad" without my knowledge and had nothing as it's value.  Removing the key helped resolve my issue.

[image]

Comment: That was the exact case for me. You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple Docs, the icons must be placed on the root level of the app files.

IOS/Xcode will not go under directories to search your image.

Solution is to move the images onto the root of your application i.e. where your source files are, or you can create references in the same way.

Regards
Heider

Answer (score 2):

My issue ended up being I had used jpg images, rather than pngs.

Comment: The marketing guy had renamed the BMP files in .png in my case. WTF !

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just needed to clean and rebuild my project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a couple of hours finally I could resolved it, copying an old -info.plist from one of my backups project and replace it, this works fine for me. 
Regards

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I updated Build Rules > Using > to "Asset Catalog Compiler"
instead of any custom script and it worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Following the steps everyone provided did not help. However, it was because of my own ignorance. I had an issue with duplicate resources being created and one of the suggestions was to remove items from copy bundle resources. Well, it never mentioned that the asset folder was required to be in there so I deleted it. After fighting with this issue for 5 hours and recalling that it use to be in copy bundle resources I added it back and the app Icons worked.
[Xcode copy bundle with appropriate file included.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ4Ej.jpg)

1. make sure you create your appicons with an image 1024x1024
2. make sure you set 'app icon source' (project > general > App Icons and launch images) to the appropriate icon folder.
3. make sure you have not deleted the copy bundle resource for said app icon folder like i did.
4. cocoapods has a forum for a specific issue if all else fails.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a much simpler solution than the others listed here. I had simply got the assets the wrong size. I had not paid attention to the multipliers that are necessary (e.g. 2x or 3x) and therefore the build was generating a warning for the incorrect asset sizes (which I had ignored). In my case, I corrected the image sizes and voila they appeared in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

For a macOS/OSX application, you also need to always add a 128 pixel size (and 2x), you can not only use a 512 pixel size and expect it to size down.

Answer (score 0):

If your app icon has any transparency then it won't work. Check it!

Answer (score 0):

I had all the images in the relevant folders and when I right clicked on the empty icon image  in `Images.xcassets/AppIcon` and chose `show in finder` it would find the image correctly and show it, but for whatever reason it wasn't adding correctly to the project.

After trying a lot of different things above I simply dragged the images from finder into the AppIcon area and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoapods be sure to check this answer from a related question. After many lost hours, this is what fixed it for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349476/1343140

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9.3:

1. Open your project and add AppIcon images.
2. Click on general, go to "App Icon and Launch Image"
   [image]
3. Click "App Icon resource" and add AppIcon (In my case it added AppIcon-1, so you can use that on rename that and do above step  again).